# Why this overloading issue in calling in CM13 and/or Android 6.0?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, security, calls

Situation: there are cases where calling priority order is by-passed and/or overloaded about 1/20 of all times by other application, which I think is critical because of many things. 
Do

1. Have 3.5 mm plug your phone and listen to music.
2. Unplug 3.5 mmm plug

   - you see that Spotify has stopped playing when inspecting it in the notification bar and hearing no music anymore
3. Do nothing with your phone in two hours
4. Call with your phone after two hours
5. You hear Spotify's music, instead of dialing -sound.
6. Stop calling.
7. Call again. The dialing starts Spotify's music which hides dialling -sound and the sound of the other person. The other person can answer your call but you will not here his/her sound, because Spotify is higher in the priority order, which should not be possible. I reproduced this five times.

Output when calling: the music of Spotify. 
Expected output: dialing sound. 
Vulnerable bug/issue because

1. unplugging 3.5 mm did not stop music
2. starting calling prioritized Spotify first, hiding completely the dialling sound, although this should not be possible

The point (2) is the thing which should be studied much more closely.

### Similar issues with Spotify in CM13

- *[S]omething strange with the audio subsystems. Once my phone started blurting out spotify music without even having spotify started, I had to reboot as to get it to stop as spotify wasn't running but still it was, phantom spotify*. ([pitrus-](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/orig-development/rom-official-cyanogenmod-13-t3392278/post68535292#post68535292))
- ...

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: CyanogenMod 13 Nightly 20160818-NIGHTLY-oneplus2; testing and reproducing now in Android 6.0
Rooted: no
Developer mode active: no
Recovery mode: TWRP 3.0.2
CM13 forum: https://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/128839-why-this-overloading-issue-in-calling-in-oneplus-2-of-cm13/
XDA forum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/orig-development/rom-official-cyanogenmod-13-t3392278/page232#post68535053

Comment: Just direct those questions to XDA threads... It's not like the question is not genuine, but we CM13 users are arguably a minority here, and OP2's is new and understandably buggy.

Comment: @AndyYan I extended the thread to XDA forum and CM13 forum. Please, see the body.

Comment: Nice :) I never downvoted your questions though... (I feel your agony as a CM user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed lastly to reproduce the problem in CM13 ROM. So it is CM13 specific. They have just one maintainer for the phone, which is too little, for my demands. I moved back to OxygenOS because they have several teams and old CM developers working for the ROM. 
This is my second CM phone which has such critical weaknesses. 
The other reason for the change is that that CM13 system breaks each time when you update it. You have to wipe nearly everything to have a stable update/upgrade. 
In short, reasons to move from CM13 to OxygenOS in Oneplus 2

1. Support teams of old CM developers, OxygenOS and HydrogenOS working for the ROM.
2. Support of continuous stable updates and upgrades for OxygenOS.
3. Knowledge of the hardware for better software.
4. Aim to be Nexus-like environment.
5. Responsive customer support.

Reasons to leave CM

1. No continuous stable updates and upgrades of CM in all phones where I have used CM.
2. No teams working for individual phones. Those little bugs can be critical, which I cannot have.
3. No resources to think, define and fix customers' issues/bug-reports of the ROM for individual devices.
4. No hardware knowledge and development so less vertical understanding.
5. Unresponsive customer support.

Comment: Well, CM works largely because of its maintainer mechanism, you can't expect them to shell out resources and treat you as a customer - in fact that's an unreasonable demand for any custom ROM out there. Oxygen only has support because it's not so "custom" - it's under the wings of 1+. Also, it's natural to expect some bleeding when on the cutting edge.

Comment: I do agree that the bug reporter (JIRA) can be _much_ more open, and that individual maintainers may need to watch bug reports more closely. Having used CM on tens of devices I'd say that the experience indeed largely depends on whether the dev is on XDA to collect bugs, and whether he's keen at fixing it.

Comment: @AndyYan Customers have money. Make Commercial Nexus-like systems on CM13 for some phones. I think CM needs to make more business with their systems. Now, they will fail because too few resources put on the software. There are customers who want continuous improvements and are ready to pay for it.

Comment: CyanogenMod is not a company! Cyngn is, and their CyanogenOS sounds closer to what you want. CM is about being FOSS, staying on the cutting edge and letting every and all devices join the fun (with the participation of individual maintainers), not about stability, as you can see from their move of getting rid of "stable" build monikers. Sounds like you're asking too much.